# The HTTP redirect request failed in UWP C# project

Tags: c#, url, redirect, uwp, http-redirect

I'm getting this error "The HTTP redirect request failed" when I'm trying to get text (whole string) of this url (for example) : "https://apic-desktop.musixmatch.com/ws/1.1/macro.subtitles.get?format=json&q_track=Mi%20Mi%20Mi%20%28Radio%20Edit%29&q_artist=SEREBRO&user_language=en&subtitle_format=mxm&app_id=web-desktop-app-v1.0&usertoken=*SECRET TOKEN*" but it's worked in chrome and I must get that json file https://pastebin.com/GJdLK3BA (I uploaded it to Pastebin)

Platform:UWP x64
System:Windows 10 pro April Update

```
public string URLToString(string url)
{
    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
    HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync(url).Result;
    string result = null;
    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
       result = client.GetStringAsync(url).Result;
    }
    else
    {
       result = null;
    }
    return result;
 }

LyURL = "https://apic-desktop.musixmatch.com/ws/1.1/matcher.lyrics.get?format=json&q_track=" + Uri.EscapeUriString(Title.Text) + "&q_artist=" + Uri.EscapeUriString(Arti.Text) + "&user_language=en&subtitle_format=mxm&app_id=web-desktop-app- v1.0&usertoken=*SECRET TOKEN*";

JObject jObject = JObject.Parse(URLToString(LyURL));

String Lyra = (string)jObject.SelectToken("message.body.lyrics.lyrics_body");
```

Error Message: The HTTP redirect request failed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`Windows.Web.Http.Headers`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/dn252713) namespace supports creation of HTTP headers and cookies, which are then associated as properties with `HttpRequestMessage` and `HttpResponseMessage` objects. Please add `header = "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 10.0; Windows NT 6.2; WOW64; Trident/6.0)";` before send get request like the following. For more detail please refer this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/networking/httpclient#send-a-simple-get-request-over-http).

```
public async void SendGetMethod(string url, Action<HttpResponseMessage> resopnse)
{
    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
    var headers = client.DefaultRequestHeaders;
    string header = "";
    if (!headers.UserAgent.TryParseAdd(header))
    {
        // throw new Exception("Invalid header value: " + header);
    }
    header = "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 10.0; Windows NT 6.2; WOW64; Trident/6.0)";
    if (!headers.UserAgent.TryParseAdd(header))
    {
        throw new Exception("Invalid header value: " + header);
    }
    HttpResponseMessage httpResponse = new HttpResponseMessage();
    Uri requestUri = new Uri(url);
    try
    {
        httpResponse = await client.GetAsync(requestUri);
        httpResponse.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
        resopnse(httpResponse);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Debug.Write("Error: " + ex.HResult.ToString("X") + " Message: " + ex.Message);
    }
}
```

**Usage**

```
SendGetMethod("url",(res)=>{
                 var result = res
            });
```

Comment: how do I use HttpResponseMessage as Action (BTW I tried the sample that in the document and simply the app crashed without error)

Comment: @AhmedWalid, I posted usage, Please note you need use `Windows.Web.Http` but not  `System.Net.Http`

Answer (score 0):

[image]I tried this example and it worked for me. Using HttpWebRequest and setting a CookieContainer will hopefully solve the problem

```
string url = @"https://apic-desktop.musixmatch.com/ws/1.1/macro.subtitles.get?format=json&q_track=Mi%20Mi%20Mi%20%28Radio%20Edit%29&q_artist=SEREBRO&user_language=en&subtitle_format=mxm&app_id=web-desktop-app-v1.0&usertoken=SECRET TOKEN";

string res;

    HttpWebRequest webReq = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(url);
                try
                {
                    webReq.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
                    webReq.Method = "GET";
                    using (WebResponse response = webReq.GetResponse())
                    {
                        using (Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream())
                        {
                            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream);
                            res = reader.ReadToEnd();
                          }
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {}
```

Comment: tried it again it is working , shared the snapshot as well. You must be missing something. try again.